# php login file depending on user membership

Tags: php

I'm trying to write something in php that redirects a user to a php file depending on membership. There are two memberships files that display different html pages depending on membership which is read from database. When user signs up it is either membership1.php or memebrship2.php. One of them will be marked as 1 in database.

Note: I'm not sure if this a right approach (two files or all in one?)

The issue I'm having is that whether I login with membeship1 or membership2 I can still open the page to the other membership by editing the url. //site/membership1 edit to>//site/membership2 will open with that content.

I don't want users from either membership to open the other page.

Can someone please help or advise?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just do 1 file, and only show the page data depending on membership type - `if(is_membership1()){....} else if(is_membership2()) {...}`. This way they can only see the membership type they are, and there is not another page that you have to monitor

Answer (score 1):

You can display info depending on members membership on a single page. Since membership type is stored in database, you can define a variable that will represent 1 or 2. All you need to do is to put this code into ur page:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/membership'.$type.'.php');
```

Comment: This combined with the comment from Sean above seems the optimal approach.  One URL, multiple states.  Using an include gets you the benefit of separate files.

Comment: Thanks guys. Will the "include" code hide the php files? I mean will it display the files in the url? Basically I don't want users to just type the other membership php file name into url and redirect themselves as they like. I might need to look at those permissions that Victor mentioned. I have tried it with the php?id= but that still does the same if I change the ID number.

Comment: @ppstacknow it will hide urls, even mozilla firebug will not show em

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create groups of users with access permission (in your case these groups would memberships). If the two pages have something in common, leave a URL access in one file, and that file to display the content according to the group to which the user belongs.

Simply create a table in the database for the groups (which have the name and ID), create a field in the user table associating it to a group by ID (foreign key), and another table permissions by setting an index for permission and to which group it belongs (plus a foreign key).

It is a simple, but effective. Recommend studying more about permission and access systems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I want to thank you guys first. I did use `if(is_membership1()){....} else if(is_membership2()) {...}` by checking the value in database. However I couldn't get the `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/to/membership'.$type.'.php');` working as my server points somewhere else.

So I kept the two files using the `header ('Location: membership1.php)` and else `header ('Location: membership2.php)` and it worked, but I still had the issue of just typing in the url the name of any  membership file which then opened.

What I did was after my function is_logged_in `if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) == true {return true;}` added `$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];` which then passed the username to the membership page and I could check against it in the database if he is membership1 or 2. 
Finally in each membership file I added a if statement for example in membership1 I added `if ($resultfromdatabase==2){header ('Location: membership2.php) exit;}` and it just redirects back to the membership2 page without opening the membership1 page.

Is this a good approach?